# With polynomial long division, why are the un-applied divisor terms still multiplied and subtracted?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility, rational-functions

Given the following for example:

$$\frac{x^2+x+8}{x+2}$$

*The first point of confusion:*

The divisor $x + 2$ when performing the division operation, only $x$ is applied. While this works with $x$ dividing $x^2$ fully, if the divisor is $x - 2$ or $x$ is a negative (e.g. $-5 + 2$) than it seems there is a logical problem as this modifies the division scalability relationship of $x$ to $x^2$.

Furthermore, dividing just by $x$ violates my understanding of quotative division in that it is returning how many $x + 2$ overlap with $x^2$. Not how many times just $x$ divides it.

*The second point of confusion:*

After Division by $x$ the partial quotient is then multiplied by the divisor and subtracted:

$$Divide(Partial-quotient):$$ $$\frac{x^2+x+8}{x+2} = x$$

$$(Confusion) Multiply:$$ $$x(x+2) = (x^2+2x)$$

$$Subtract:$$ $$\frac{x^2+x+8}{x+2} - (x^2 + 2x) = \frac{-x+8}{x+2}$$

Why is the partial quotient multiplied by the constant term 2 in "$x$ + **2**" and then the product of 2 is removed? The purpose of subtraction is to eliminate the portion of the dividend $x^2 + x + 8$ that has already been divided. Yet it does not appear the $2$ was involved in the division, so it seems we are removing more than necessary.

Comment: There is a misprint after Subtract. You subtract $x$ or $x(x+2)$ in the numerator

Comment: "While in this specific case it is not a concern..." I'm not understanding where your confusion lies here, so I would advise using a case that you *are* concerned about as an example instead.

Comment: @TheoBendit updated and removed.

Comment: I fixed a few typos in my answer, Sorry if they caused any confusion.

Answer (score 5):

The point of the first step in the long division of polynomials is to figure out how to reduce the degree of the polynomial you are dividing.

In your example that means writing
$$
 x^2+x+8 = a(x+2) + b
$$
where you choose the value of $a$ so that the $x^2$ term will cancel. Clearly $a$ should be just $x$. Then that choice tells you what $b$ must be. In your example it is $-x + 8$.

Once you've done this, you do it all over again to reduce the degree of $b$. So your new problem is
$$
-x+8 = a(x+2) + b .
$$
In this problem $a = -1$ and $b$ works out to $10$. That's of degree less than the degree of $x+2$ so it's the remainder and you are done.

(Can you understand why that $10$ is just what you get when you substitute $-2$ for $x$ in the original polynomial?)

You should think of this algorithm as analogous to the long division algorithm for integer arithmetic. There your goal at each step is to deal with the leftmost digit of the dividend. In fact the polynomial algorithm is easier because you never have to "carry" or "borrow". The powers of $x$ never mix in the way the powers of $10$ can in arithmetic.

You will understand this better when you think only about multiplication.
Writing
$$
\frac{x^2+x+8}{x+2} = x
$$
is confusing nonsense: those two expressions are not equal.

Comment: Thank you for responding with this depth. My understanding of Poly div now is that because Multiplication and Division are inverses of one another, we are building a quotient that when multiplied by the divisor equals the dividend. This is why we can get a negative variable in the quotient (which is a result of this building), but when calculated and summed when 'x = 6' will have the same answer whether you use the quotient or the original expression. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: I don't understand "negative variable" or "$x=6$". Given dividend $p(x)$ and divisor $d(x)$ you find quotient $q(x)$ and remainder $r(x)$ so that the polynomial identity $p(x) = q(x)d(x) + r(x)$ is true. Then you can substitute any value of $x$ you wish in either side of that equation and get the same numerical answer.

Comment: Please strive not to answer duplicate questions. The problems students have with basic operations have been covered many times over on the site already.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Even Bill Dubuque, who is even more vigilant than you at flagging duplicate questions, thought this one needed an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The idea behind the inductive step of the polynomial division algorithm for $\,G\div F\,$ is as follows. Write $\, G  = ax^{k+j}+g,\,$ $\,F = x^k + f \,$ as its (highest degree) lead_term plus lower degree terms.    We scale the divisor $F$ by the quotient of the *leading* terms $\,\color{#c00}{ax^j} = (ax^{k+j}/x^k)\,$ so that it has the *same leading term* as $G$, so it kills the lead term of $G$ when subtracted from $\,G,\,$ leaving a new $\,\color{#0a0}{G'}$ of *lower degree* than $G.\,$ We repeat this process, dividing $\,\color{#0a0}{G'}$ by $F,\,$ etc, iterating until we reach a polynomial of lower degree than $F$ (which is the remainder $\,G\bmod F).\,$ Below are the equations and associated tabular form of this inductive step:

$$\begin{align} 
G - \color{#c00}{a x^{\large j}} F \,\ = \,\   \overbrace{a x^{\large k+j} + g}^{\large {\rm dividend}\ G}\ -\  &\color{#c00}{a x^{\large j}} (\!\!\overbrace{x^{\large k} + f\!}^{\large {\rm divisor}\ F})\ \!=\!\!\!\! \overbrace{\color{#0a0}{g-ax^j f}}^{\large {\rm deg}\ \color{#0a0}{G'}\ <\ \deg G\!}\\[.6em]
\underset{\!\!\!\!\!\!\large \div\ (x^k+f)}\Longrightarrow\ \ \ \dfrac{a x^{\large k+j}+g}{x^{\large k}+f}\, =\ &\color{#c00}{a x^{\large j}}\ \ +  \underbrace{\dfrac{\color{#0a0}{g-a x^{\large j} f}}{x^k + f}}_{\large\rm recurse\ on\ this}\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$
$$\require{enclose}
\qquad\ \ \  \begin{array}{r}
                \color{#c00}{a x^j}\phantom{x^{k+n}+f\ \ \,}  \\[0pt]
{\Large \smash[t]{\overset{\rm\color{#90f}{tabularly}}{\leadsto^{\phantom{.}}}}}\quad\  x^k\!+f\,\ \enclose{longdiv}{\,\ a x^{k+j}\,+\,g\phantom{x^kg}} \\[-3pt]
                  \underline{ax^{k+j}\ +\, a x^j f} \\
                                  \color{#0a0}{g\,-\,a x^j f = G'}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! 
\end{array}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$$

**Remark** $ $ The same method works if the leading coef of the divisor is not $1$, as long as it is a unit (invertible), so it divides  *every* coefficient, so the above inductive step is *always* possible  - cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. My understanding is that because Multiplication and Division are inverses, the quotient is built off of this principle. As a side effect this is why we can get a negative variable in the quotient, but whether you use the original expression or quotient when x is given a value, the answer will be the same. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Mark As explained above, the quotient $\,\color{#c00}{ax^j}$ is chosen so that it scales the divisor $F$ to have the same leading coefficient as the dividend $G$, so subtracting them yields a smaller division problem, i.e. a smaller degree dividend $G'$ upon which we recursively (inductively) divide by $F.\ \ $

Comment: @Mark The key property governing the inductive (degree) descent  in the (Euclidean) polynomial division algorithm is that the lead term of the quotient $\,Q = G\div F\,$  is the quotient of the lead terms $\,\ell(Q) = \ell(G\div F) = \ell(G)/\ell(F).\,$ Generally $\,QF = (qx^i+s)(bx^k+f)\,$ and $\,G = ax^{k+j}+g\,$ have equal leading terms $\iff qb x^{i+j} = a x^{k+j}\iff i=k\,$ & $\,q = a/b$ $\iff \ell(Q) = qx^i = ax^{k+j}/(bx^j) = \ell(G)/\ell(F),\,$ as claimed. $\ \ $

Comment: Please strive not to answer duplicates.

Comment: @Jyrki Please strive to give *good* applicable dupe targets. It is possible (though unlikely) that it is a dupe but I don't agree that it is a dupe of [that,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170455/242) since it is highly unlikely that any of the answers there will help to remedy this OP's (seemingly unique) confusions.

Comment: I concur, I had read your linked @BillDubuque and still was confused.

Comment: @Mark I think you meant to ping the dupe link author Jyrki, not I.